# How do I access a global MongoDB connection from a handler?

Tags: mongodb, haskell, state, haskell-snap-framework

I’m trying to make a simple web application using Snap. I want to have a global MongoDB connection which I can use across handlers.

I open this connection in `appInit`, which works.

```
data App = App { _mongoDB :: Pipe -- connection
               }

appInit :: SnapletInit App App
appInit = makeSnaplet "site" "My Site" Nothing $ do
    db <- liftIO $ do
        pipe <- runIOE $ connect (host "127.0.0.1")
        return pipe
    return $ App db
```

However, I have no idea how to access this connection (`_mongoDB`) from a handler. I tried several things, including the following, but I get type errors every time.

```
watchHandler :: Handler App App ()
watchHandler = do
    res <- liftIO $ do
        pipe <- gets _mongoDB -- type error
        results <- access pipe master "db" (find $ select [] "movies")
        return results

    writeBS "test"
```

It gives me the following error:

```
No instance for (MonadState App IO)
  arising from a use of `gets'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (MonadState App IO)
In a stmt of a 'do' block: pipe <- gets _mongoDB
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `do { pipe <- gets _mongoDB;
        results <- access pipe master "db" (find $ select [] "movies");
        return results }'
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  res <- liftIO
         $ do { pipe <- gets _mongoDB;
                results <- access pipe master "db" (find $ select [] "movies");
                return results }
```

It confuses the hell out of me. How can I access my MongoDB connection from a handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `liftIO` block is just for IO operations, accessing the application state needs to be done in the `Handler` monad itself.

```
watchHandler :: Handler App App ()
watchHandler = do
    pipe <- gets _mongoDB
    res <- liftIO $ do
        results <- access pipe master "db" (find $ select [] "movies")
        return results

    writeBS "test"
```

Also, binding a value and then immediately returning it is redundant. You can just write:

```
watchHandler :: Handler App App ()
watchHandler = do
    pipe <- gets _mongoDB
    res <- liftIO $ access pipe master "db" (find $ select [] "movies")

    writeBS "test"
```